# Run python script for HTML web page

Tags: python, html, django, apache, ubuntu

i need to create a website.
The website needs to run a Python script once the user enters the data. I have searched the net for over a week now and haven't found any help. 
Everybody just tells me to download DJango framework, but no body shows how to run python scripts in html web pages.
I dont have any experience in web design as it is not my field. But i do know a bit of python scripting and some html.
Any kind of help that puts me into right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Python runs on the server.  HTML is rendered on the client.  Django is a framework that helps you inject data into your html templates.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to run Python scripts within a web page in the same way that Javascript runs within a web page, this is not possible, because web browsers don't natively understand Python.

If you want to run Python code that generates an HTML page, you can use a framework like Django or Flask, which will require a server that supports this kind of framework (long running processes). You can also use a CGI Python script to do this, which will require your web server to have Python installed and be set up to run CGI scripts.

Embedding Python in a HTML in the same way that PHP is embedded in an HTML page is generally not done in Python - it is considered an anti-pattern that leads to security problems and lots of bad practices. Python folks will generally not help you shoot yourself in the foot, unlike other communities, so you won't find much help for what is considered the wrong thing. Some template engines like Mako support using Python within templates to generate the HTML markup, but you will need to use it in conjunction with some other web framework to handle the HTTP request.

Comment: ... not possible ... _unless_ there is a Python interpreter implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: I just came here from google, this will let you run python from php `<?php  
exec('python HelloPython.py', $output, $return); 
?>`

Answer (score 4):

If you **really** want to run python on the client like javascript,
take a look at: [**Brython**](http://brython.info), [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) or [pyris](http://pyjs.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "run python scripts in html web pages". Everyone tells you to use something like Django because if you want to make a dynamic web site that executes server-side code in response to user input you need something like Django or some other server-side web framework. So you have already been put into the right direction but ignored that.